# Sorting an array of votes by highest upvote to downvote ratio and vice versa

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting, ecmascript-6

I have an array of characters that people can vote on and the votes gets stored in the array.

I made two new arrays from it and I want to sort the first one so that characters with the best upvote to downvote ratio (after subtracting downvotes from upvotes) are at the front of the array, and the second one should be the exact opposite.

My comparison function for the first array is returning an array where Edward, with a ratio of 2:1 upvotes to downvotes is ahead of Magnetic and Goku, which both have a ratio of 1:0 upvotes to downvotes, which is incorrect; they should be ahead of Edward on the array.

```js
const characters = [
  { name: 'Sharpe', upvotes: 2, downvotes: 0 },
  { name: 'Edward', upvotes: 4, downvotes: 2 },
  { name: 'Magnetic', upvotes: 1, downvotes: 0 },
  { name: 'The', upvotes: 1, downvotes: 0 },
  { name: 'Goku', upvotes: 2, downvotes: 0 },
  { name: 'Zeros', upvotes: 1, downvotes: 1 }
];

characters.sort((a, b) => {
  return (b.upvotes - b.downvotes) - (a.upvotes - a.downvotes);
});

console.log(characters);
```

Comment: It just seems that your compare functions for the sorts are not doing what the comments above them say. For array 1 you aren't subtracting the down votes `(b.upvotes - b.downvotes) - (a.upvotes - a.downvotes)`

Comment: I don't see you subtracting down votes from up votes. Only up votes from up votes and down votes from down votes. Please review your sorted logic.

Comment: @Peeper not sure why you didn't just [edit and undelete this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47974883/1541563)....

Comment: @Patrick Roberts Thanks, I will definitely do it that way from now on. Sorry, I'm still new here.

Comment: `upvotes - downvotes` is not a *ratio*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison functions look a little bit off:

```
(a, b) => {
  return b.upvotes - a.downvotes
}
```

compares the downvotes for `a` with the upvotes of `b` - you're not actually comparing the  **ratio of a**  with the  **ratio of  b**.

You'll have to calculate the ratio for  both  `a` and `b` separately - with something like `a.upvotes - a.downvotes` (and similar for `b`) - and then compare them.

```js
const characters = [
  { name: 'Edward', upvotes: 21, downvotes: 30 },
  { name: 'Sharpe', upvotes: 37, downvotes: 200 },
  { name: 'And', upvotes: 45, downvotes: 3 },
  { name: 'The', upvotes: 0, downvotes: 0 },
  { name: 'Magnetic', upvotes: 1, downvotes: 0 },
  { name: 'Zeros', upvotes: 37, downvotes: 100 }
];

characters.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.downvotes == 0 && b.downvotes == 0) {
      return b.upvotes - a.upvotes;
  }
  else if (a.downvotes == 0 && a.upvotes > 0) {
      return -1;
  }
  else if (b.downvotes == 0 && b.upvotes > 0) {
      return 1;
  }
  return (b.upvotes - b.downvotes) - (a.upvotes - a.downvotes);
});

console.log(characters);
```

Comment: Magnetic should be ahead of 'And' because he has 1:0 ratio of upvotes to downvotes. Is there any way to do this? I updated my question with your solution and edited the code snippet in a way that demonstrates the flaw I mentioned. Thanks for helping me figure this out.

Comment: Edited my solution - try it out now. I assumed you want something like 1 upvote, 0 downvote to be above 2 upvotes, 1 downvote. Also assumed that 0 up 0 down is above something like 1 upvote, 2 downvotes. It's not a very elegant looking solution since I wanted to just whip it up really quickly, but hopefully it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const characters = [
  { name: 'Edward', upvotes: 21, downvotes: 30 },
  { name: 'Sharpe', upvotes: 37, downvotes: 200 },
  { name: 'And', upvotes: 45, downvotes: 3 },
  { name: 'The', upvotes: 0, downvotes: 0 },
  { name: 'Magnetic', upvotes: 1, downvotes: 0 },
  { name: 'Zeros', upvotes: 37, downvotes: 100 }
];

characters.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.downvotes == 0 && b.downvotes == 0) {
      return b.upvotes - a.upvotes;
  }
  else if (a.downvotes == 0 && a.upvotes > 0) {
      return -1;
  }
  else if (b.downvotes == 0 && b.upvotes > 0) {
      return 1;
  }
  return (b.upvotes - b.downvotes) - (a.upvotes - a.downvotes);
});

console.log(characters);
```